# Javascript reference object by an identifier or reference it directly?

Tags: javascript, object, memory

I am creating quite many objects in Javascript, which I need to be able to reference to retrieve later, for example through an array. Now I am wondering how to save the object reference in the array.

The objects will interract with an external library, which can function either with object IDs or the object itself. I know Javascript treats object variables like pointers and not object copies, so is it safe to reference the objects directly ?

At first I was thinking "if I save the IDs of the objects, that would keep memory usage low", but is this true ? How much memory does an object variable* consume versus an integer variable ?

*the pointer to the object, not the object data

Also, if saving the objects directly is the way to go, is it ok to use `array.push()` to add the new object to the array ? Is `array.push()` creating a copy or does it work like a variable ?

Comment: "[...] is it safe to reference the objects directly ?" yes. "How much memory does an object variable* consume versus an integer variable ?" - that is not specified, but any memory usage here is completely negligible. Optimizing JS compilers store compact 31-bit signed integer arrays quite efficiently (32 bit per integer). Object (references) might take up 64 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference the objects directly. If you really care about memory usage, I'd say the way of passing the ids will use more memory since you'll have to maintain another set of mappings.

Passing the objects directly will let the JavaScript engine to work directly with the object references. That's not affecting the memory usage, as long you don't to any cloning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the relevant question is weather or not saving an integer and using that as an identifier later is more effective than saving a reference to the object.

I'd go with the reference in an array. the size of a reference vs a number is going to be negligible.